# How to loop through retrieve div-id

Tags: python, selenium

I try to retrieve posts - title, url and image from a website using selenium. I have get to the first level, but on second level the post starts from (div id="abcde-11-0") to (div id="abcde-11-20"), in this case how should I get into second level before I can reach the (a herf) to retrieve the data?

Here are my code:

```
# I get to the first level by using xpath
Container=chromedrv.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id="MainContent"]/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/div[2]")
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if I understood your question correctly, but please use this code.

```
first_level_rows =chromedrv.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainContent"]/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/div[2]')

for first_level_row in first_level_rows:
    second_level_rows = first_level_row.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "abcde-11-")]')
```

find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "abcde-11-")]') => This part extracts all tags contains "abcde-11-" in id.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed but it come error - no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@id,'HomePageInternational-riverPlus-, 11-')]"}

Comment: Hello, Where did you see "HomePageInternational-riverPlus-,"? I can't see it in your post of ask.